# How to I display multi-line text in grafana

Tags: grafana, multiline

I am trying to make a panel in grafana, that will show all the failed services on my ubuntu server. I wasn't able to do that with any visualization I tried.

I've created a small script that telegraf runs every 10 minutes, and then inserts the data into influxdb

```
./show_failed_services.sh
UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
isc-dhcp-server.service      loaded failed failed ISC DHCP IPv4 server
isc-dhcp-server6.service     loaded failed failed ISC DHCP IPv6 server
systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules
```

I am trying to create a panel that will show these failed services, but I didn't find how to do it.
Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table Panel` to show data.
Eg: https://play.grafana.org/d/U_bZIMRMk/table-panel-showcase?orgId=1

Answer (score 0):

I did tried to use the table panel and all the other visualisations but because the data was unstructured, everything failed. So yesterday I had a revaltion, that I can structure the data into a csv, that is easly imported by telegraf in grafana so I did this script:

```
echo "unix_time","failed_service"
sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --state failed --no-legend  |awk '{print $1}' | sed  's/.service//g' | awk '{ system( "echo $(date +%s),$(sleep 1)"$1 ) }'
```

After this, it was a simple matter of creating the table as you can see in this screen shot
[the end result in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFu43.png)